# Parsing strings with grep/str_extract

Tags: r, text-mining

As part of my feature engineering, I need to parse text strings from different languages and keep text enclosed within parentheses.  Everything was going well until I encountered a very strange phenomenon.  For some languages, the parentheses I need to find look slightly different, and various regexp options fail.

I'm pasting screen-shots because strangely, copying and pasting the strange parentheses changes it to a 'normal' one, so I can't set up a different regex to find those separately.

[image]

Notice that the parentheses in the first entry look normal, but for the second entry, it appears sort of 'sharp'

[image]

If I use stringr's str_extract, the first instance works fine, but the second fails.

[image]

But, the encodings are the same. Anyone know what's going on?

[Edit: here are the results of dput on these same examples. dput apparently sees the parentheses as equivalent, even though grep does not]

```
c("Obnaružena poterâ šaga na (Motor šprica pipettora R1).", "(STAT tàn zhen Z zhóu ma dá) tàn cè dào diu bù<U+3002>")
```

Finally, I am actually copy and pasting the two parentheses from R into the code window below; they do appear different this way. First is normal, second is the strange one.

```
(  （
```

Comment: Could you please post the output of `dput(x$MESSAGE2[73:74])`?

Comment: Sure; Different example but here is the dput:
"<U+6E2C><U+5B9A><U+9805><U+76EE><U+3092><U+51E6><U+7406><U+3067><U+304D><U+307E><U+305B><U+3093><U+3002>(R1 <U+30DF><U+30C9><U+30EB><U+8A66><U+85AC>) <U+3067> (R1 <U+30D4><U+30DA><U+30C3><U+30BF>) <U+306E><U+5438><U+5F15><U+30A8><U+30E9><U+30FC><U+3067><U+3059><U+3002>"

Comment: please edit the full dput output into the question itself and update the examples in the question for this new output.